# ¿Como se utiliza gulp-webp?

Tags: gulp

Así es como me enseñaron a usarlo en un video:

```
const {src, dest, watch} = require('gulp');
const webp = require('gulp-webp');

function web( done ){
    const opciones = {
        quality: 50
    }

    src("src/img/**/*.{jpg,png}")
        .pipe(webp(opciones))
        .pipe(dest("build/img"))
    done()
}

exports.web = web;
```

Pero cuando intento cargarlo me salta este error:

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\zurbr\OneDrive\Escritorio\Curso Desarrollo Web\FestivalMusica_inicio\node_modules\gulp-webp\index.js from C:\Users\zurbr\OneDrive\Escritorio\Curso Desarrollo Web\FestivalMusica_inicio\gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\zurbr\OneDrive\Escritorio\Curso Desarrollo Web\FestivalMusica_inicio\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at Object. (C:\Users\zurbr\OneDrive\Escritorio\Curso Desarrollo Web\FestivalMusica_inicio\gulpfile.js:23:14) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

El video que vi, es de 2022. Pienso que tal vez una actualizacion de la dependencia, cambio la forma de usarlo. Agradeceria si alguien puede ayudarme.

He intentado cambiar el require de gulp-webp por un import, con eso ejecuta el codigo. Pero comienzan a aparecer errores, como que src no es una funcion, webp no es una funcion, dest no es una funcion y asi.

Answer (score 0):

El error que se te muestra indica que el modulo está basado en la arquitectura de modulos "ES modules" (ECMAScript) y lo estás importando en tu programa que está hecho usando "CommonJS modules".

Intentar importar un modulo de ECMAScript usando `require()`, que es la forma de importar en CommonJS es un error. Tienes dos opciones, cambiar toda la estructura de tu proyecto a ES modules o cambiar la forma de importarlo.

La segunda opción es la más sencilla, pero deberías hacer algunos cambios en tu código.

```js
async function web( done ){
  const opciones = {
    quality: 50
  }

  const webp = (await import("gulp-webp")).default; 

  console.log(webp)
  src("src/img/**/*.{jpg,png}")
    .pipe(webp(opciones))
    .pipe(dest("build/img"))
  // done()
}
```

Lo primero es hacer que la función "web" sea asíncrona.

```
async function web( done )
```

Luego, dentro de la función, importar "gulp-webp" con la función de importación dinámica "import()".

```
await import("gulp-webp")
```

Esta función "import()" devuelve el módulo en si. Por ello, para acceder a la función "gulpWebp()" (que es lo que exporta "gulp-webp" por defecto) debes usar la propiedad "default".

```
const webp = (await import("gulp-webp")).default
```

Esta solución funciona asumiendo que solo vas a usar "webp()" dentro de la función "web()".